# how i can set variable in join table codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want to get tbl_systemstatus.systemid value as variable to use in same where clause.
Now any one can give me solution how i can create variable of tbl_systemstatus.systemid to use in same query to search data.

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('tbl_systemstatus');

$this->db->join('newsystem as system', 'system.ID = tbl_systemstatus.systemid as $id');

$this->db->where(array('systemid' => $id,'status' => 'CISO approved'));

$this->db->order_by('tbl_systemstatus.id', 'DESC');

    $this->db->limit(1);

  $query  = $this->db->get();



  if ($query->num_rows()>0)
  {
    return $query->result();
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

with a join table, you don't need to get systemid, just enough :

```
function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(){
   $get = $this->db->query("SELECT s.*,
                                   n.*,
                            FROM tbl_systemstatus s
                            INNER JOIN newsystem n ON n.systemID = s.id

                           WHERE s.status = 'CISO Approved' 
                           ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1
                          ");
   $data = $get->result();
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: i am Multiple System Row in it. so i want to use  s.id in where clause so i can get data from that system only